# AWS Lambda: Find out (and disable) own event source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

Can a lambda function deactivate its own event source (a monthly trigger via EventBridge) without having to manually entering/configuring something?

I thought about achieving it using update_event_source_mapping:

```
response = S3_CLIENT.update_event_source_mapping(
        UUID = event_source_UUID,
        FunctionName = context.invoked_function_arn,
        Enabled = False,    
    )
```

... but to use this I  need the event_source_UUID as a parameter obviously.

To get the event_source_UUID I tried this:

```
    lambdaClient = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = lambdaClient.list_event_source_mappings(
        FunctionName=context.invoked_function_arn, 
        EventSourceArn = "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:xyz:rule/TriggerMiddleOfMonth"
        )
    print(response)
```

What happens is this error:
*An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the ListEventSourceMappings operation: Unrecognized event source. Unsupported source arn*
Also this is somehow understandable since the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-event-source-mappings.html) says that ListEventSource will only accept event sources from:

- Amazon Kinesis - The ARN of the data stream or a stream consumer.
- Amazon DynamoDB Streams - The ARN of the stream.
- Amazon Simple Queue Service - The ARN of the queue.
- Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka - The ARN of the cluster.

But how do I now find the actual event source (= the link to the event-bridge)?
Do I really have to go the other way round and poll all event source entries  that are existing in my account and then check if they have a link to my lambda function in focus?

PS:
I also didn't figure out, how to get this UUID manually.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-event-source-mappings.html gives you the list of event sources - and certainly the lambda can change its own event source mappings - probably a very bad idea, but certainly doable / possible as long as the lambda has the right IAM permissions.

Comment: I was hoping that it should work. Maybe it can be done like this: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.list_event_source_mappings   `response = client.list_event_source_mappings(
    FunctionName='my-function',
)

print(response)`. The return statement should give information about the uuid

Comment: ```list_event_source_mappings``` seems to not know anything about events coming in via the Eventbridge ...

Comment: Yes, because those are not tracked in event source mappings but at the event bridge directly, same thing for s3 notifications. You cannot find / list them unless you know where to look, especially if the rule or bucket is not within your own account.

Comment: @luk2302 so I guess the only dynamic way would be to load all EventBridge events and search for the right one that is associated with the currently running lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption:

- the affected rule is only triggering this one function of interest (no other functions are triggered by that rule)
- there is only one rule that is triggering the function of interest

Answer:

```
rules = eventClient.list_rule_names_by_target(TargetArn=context.invoked_function_arn)
response = eventClient.disable_rule(Name=rules["RuleNames"][0])
```

This of course requires that your lambda function role has either full write access to the EventBridge (which you probably don't want) or that you attach a dedicated policy

Of course, enablin.g the rule again is done using the same approach using "enable_rule"